# 2 Line segments having same end point

Tags: math

I had a question regarding 2 line segments. Say we have 2 line segments whose origin and lengths are given as: (P0, L0) and (P1, L1) respectively. I need to find when can they end at the same point. The line segments lie anywhere in 3D space.

One of the approaches I could think of is: Let's say this common end point is T and the points are A and B. So for the line segments with A and B as origins, A,B and T must form a triangle. Length of vector AT = L0 and length of vector BT = L1. But since the orientation of the line segment is not known, there can be a lot of possibilities. Lets say we choose a particular orientation for line segment AT as (i,j,k) - 1st octant. So now we can move anywhere in space  from T but only by a distance L1 to find BT.

This is where I m not sure how to move forward.

Answer (score 2):

The line segments can end in the same point if and only if the distance between `P0` and `P1` is less than or equal to `L0 + L1`. In the special case where this distance is equal to `L0 + L1` the line segments have the same orientation in space and lie on the same line.

A way to think about this is to ask if two spheres around `P0` and `P1` with radii `L0` and `L1` intersect or at least touch each other. The circle (point) of intersection (touch) is where your line segments can have the same end point.

Comment: vow! i did not think about the sphere intersection interpretation. The special case you mentioned. Are you sure they have the same orientation? That could be one of the solutions. Wouldn't d = L0 + L1 be also the case when the three points form a triangle? One more thing. Once we test for this, what range of values would be acceptable if I want to run an iteration of values to test.

Comment: I am sure they form a single line. For a detailed explanation, look up the "triangle inequality". Your triangle will be collapsed to flat line in the case of `d == L0 + L1`. No need to test. Proven math.

Comment: oh yea understood. what about the value ranges? Do I need to individually put in values because I want the function to return a list of all the valid common end points

Comment: Aha, that is harder. There are infinitely many points though in a circle. Do you want a parametric representation?

Comment: yes, i think parametric representation might be the only way to represent all the points. How else could I do it? Maybe I might need an additional constraint like the points should be within a particular region